# openwrt C cgi script

Tags: cgi

We are developing openwrt.
The web server uses lighttpd.
cgi was developed in C language.
In the html form, the action is set as cgi in the form tag, and the cgi developed in C is executed.
I put the script in cgi.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char *form, *inStr;
long inLen;

printf("Content-type: text/html%c%c\n\n",10,10);
printf("<HTML>\n");
printf("<head>\n");
inLen = strtol(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"), NULL, 10) + 1;
inStr = malloc(inLen);
memset(inStr, 0, inLen);
fgets(inStr, inLen+1, stdin);
form = web_get("page", inStr, 0);
 if (!strcmp(form, "reboot")) {
    set_reboot(inStr);




 printf("scriptype='text/javascript'>document.location.href='../index.shtml';/script>\n"); 
   }else if (!strcmp(form,"lan"))
         {
    set_lan(inStr);
   }
   free(inStr);
printf("</head>\n");
printf("</HTML>");
return 0;
```

}

After running cgi in Chrome, the script will not run.
This is what I see on the webpage.
    net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-custom = 0
    Error running command
    OK
    OK
    OK
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script 
type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='../wireless_setting.shtml'; 
</script>
</head>
</HTML>
```

I do not go to the page I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you executing this line:

```
printf("Content-type: text/html%c%c\n\n",10,10);
```

Anything placed after the above line, will not be executed, and instead be printed on the screen. The problem is in the flow of this script. You have to start printing the page only after all other operations are done.